# Scrollable tabs with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, user-interface, tabs, scrollable

i'm trying to develop a scrollable tabs with ul and overflow property but i'm kind  lost in javascript (logic problem). Could someone  help me with a library, tutorial link?

Comment: Show us what you have accomplished so far. Post a fiddle.

Comment: just add `oveflow:scroll` to content div of active tab

Comment: The code http://jsfiddle.net/jJ5Sm/